# Tkinter and multilanguage

Tags: python, tkinter, internationalization, multilingual

I have a question about application created with tkinter.
Application almost created, but now additional option must be added.

I must add extra language for widget names and for combobox options.
Here is code snippet about how initialized my widgets:

```
DISTRICTS = ["A", "B", "C"]
dist_lable = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text="Seller Name")
dist_name  = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=dist_var, state="readonly",
                                  values=DISTRICTS)
```

I want to add radiobuttons\entry to give user ability to choose language.

This application also saves some selected options when user close it and load setting at the next start. Autoload function defined just after my **init** method.
I think I can also save selected by user language to config file and then use this options to use selected language.

Now I need to choose the best way to achieve this, but only one solution I figured out yet: after function that loads my previous config reinit my app with language option:

Here is example (suppose that `LANG = AZ`):

```
ENG, AZ = 1,2
DISTRICTS = ["A", "B", "C"],[["D", "E", "F"]
dist_lable = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text=["Seller Name","Satici Adi"][LANG])
dist_name  = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=dist_var, state="readonly",
                                  values=DISTRICTS[LANG])
```

In this solution my app will be initialized with default language and will be reinitialized either will find config file or when user choose other language in GUI.

Also I think that I can write some code before tkinter which will try to load LANG from config file prior tkinter mainloop().

I'm new in programming and not sure that this way is best (because may be I can avoid reinitialization) and just ask you to suggest me new solution or comment my.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `widget.config(**options)` to change the text on the fly. For example:

```
# New language chosen here
dist_label.config(text=["Seller name", "Naam verkoper"][LANG])
```

You could also try using `StringVar()`

```
var = Tkinter.StringVar()
var.set(["Seller name", "Naam verkoper"][LANG])
lbl = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. not bad actually, but I need to write additional code for each widgets (about 40-50) when __init__ can do this work with minimum code change.

Comment: @Mikhail Tokarev I have added the method for `StringVar()`. As far as I know, there is no faster way. These are the ways it was designed to work.

Comment: You're welcome :) . If this answers your question to satisfaction, could you select it as the answer?

Comment: Of course, if don't mind lets wait a little bit, might be some one add something news.